# Is it possible to display the result of a mysql query without looping in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

**Is it possible to use an array holding the result of a mysql query and displaying it by incrementing the array index counter?**

I have this code that allows a number input from 6 to 11 and generates
2 tables dividing the number equally if possible.It generates
incremented team names (ex. team 1, team2, ...). I tried using a loop
in displaying the real team names from my database but it loops the
generation of tables also and creates so many tables.please help.

```
<?php

        $count = count($result);
        $team = $count;
        $teamctr = 1;

        if ($team > 5 && $team <= 11){
            $table = 2;
            $tblctr = 1;
            $r1ctr = 0;
            $r2ctr = 0;
            if ($team == 6){
                $row1 = 3;
                $row2 = 3;
            }
            else if ($team == 7){
                $row1 = 3;
                $row2 = 4;
            }
            else if ($team == 8){
                $row1 = 4;
                $row2 = 4;
            }
            else if ($team == 9){
                $row1 = 4;
                $row2 = 5;
            }
            else if ($team == 10){
                $row1 = 5;
                $row2 = 5;
            }
            else if ($team == 11){
                $row1 = 5;
                $row2 = 6;
            }
            while($tblctr <= $table){$i = 0;
                echo "Number of Teams: ".$team; ?><br><?php
                echo "Group Into: ".$table; ?><br><?php

                ?>
                <table border="1" align="center" width="30%">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="80%" align="center">Group &nbsp <?php echo $tblctr; ?></th>
                        <th width="10%" align="center">W</th>
                        <th width="10%" align="center">L</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                    if($tblctr = 1){
                        while($r1ctr < $row1){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Team &nbsp <?php echo $teamctr ?></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="score" maxlength="6" size="6" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="score" maxlength="6" size="6" /></td>
                        <?php
                        $r1ctr++;
                        $teamctr++;
                    }
                    echo ""; ?><br><?php
                    }
                    if($tblctr = 2){
                        ?>
                <table border="1" align="center" width="30%">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="80%" align="center">Group &nbsp <?php echo $tblctr; ?></th>
                        <th width="10%" align="center">W</th>
                        <th width="10%" align="center">L</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        while($r2ctr < $row2){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Team &nbsp <?php echo $teamctr ?></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="score" maxlength="6" size="6" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="score" maxlength="6" size="6" /></td>
                        <?php
                        $r2ctr++;
                        $teamctr++;
                    }
                    echo ""; ?><br><?php
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Done IF";
                    }

                    $tblctr++;
            }
        }
```

How can I use this query to display the team name from my database?

```
$query = "SELECT * From tbl_teams";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result) {

    $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id[$i] = $row['team_name'];   
        echo $id[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: your question makes no sense. if you're incrementing a counter, then you're basically using a loop ANYWAYS. You've simply constructed your loop wrong. You don't put an entire table into the loop, only the actual data output stuff. the `<table>` and `</table>` business goes OUTSIDE of the loop.

Comment: Nope, not possible. Also, do $i++; in your while.

Comment: I needed to put the <table> inside the loop because my code generates two tables. please try my code. sorry i'm a newbie in this php

Comment: Please help me edit my code that changes the team name into actual team names from database.
<td>Team &nbsp <?php echo $teamctr ?></td>

Comment: You should use `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: sorry don't know PDO. i'm new in web programming

Comment: @James Because you are new, you should learn the right way to access databases in PHP, which is not using `mysql_*` functions. Learn mysqli or PDO. Also, make sure you grasp the concept of looping structures.  If you are outputting mor HTML elements then desired because of a loop, then simply move the undesired elements out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your database query loop, try changing to

```
$team_names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $team_names[] = $row['team_name'];
}
```

Then in your table code, try changing it to

```
$count = count($team_names);
$team = $count;
$teamctr = 0;
```

and

```
<td>Team &nbsp <?php echo $team_names[$teamctr]; ?></td>
```